# How to convert all the elements of a for loop to a string

Tags: javascript

I have multiple letters, each written in their own span under an h1 tag, written in the HTML file. I then want to loop over these letters, and combine all the letters from the span elements into a single string that looks like this, "Hover over me!" (with the spaces). I have completed the for loop and extracted the inner HTML for each letter, but am having a hard time converting this to a single string, here is my HTML and JS code.

```js
let text = document.querySelectorAll(".letter");
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  let array = [];
  let letters = text[i].innerHTML;
  console.log(letters);
}
```

```html
<h1>
    <span class="letter">H</span>
    <span class="letter">o</span>
    <span class="letter">V</span>
    <span class="letter">E</span>
    <span class="letter">R</span>
    <span> </span>
    <span class="letter">O</span>
    <span class="letter">V</span>
    <span class="letter">E</span>
    <span class="letter">R</span>
    <span> </span>
    <span class="letter">M</span>
    <span class="letter">E</span>
    <span class="letter">!</span>
</h1>>
```

Comment: Note: ids have to be unique. One per page.

Comment: `[...document.querySelectorAll('h1 span')].map(x => x.innerText).join('')`

Comment: you can do letters.join(' ')

Comment: You want to use class="letter" not id.  This is invalid HTML

Comment: Updated code, nothing mentioned here has worked.

Comment: Do you want the final string to look like the text as it is displayed in the html document, complete with spaces between letters caused by the span breaks?

Comment: Yes. @DavePritlove I want it to output a string "Hover over me!"

Comment: so not what's displayed where each letter has a space forced by the spans, you want those spaces removed and just have the spaces inserted between words.

Comment: @amax you're resetting the array on each iteration. Did you mean to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all the span elements, iterate over them taking their text content, and shove that into an array. If the letter is at first index of the str make it uppercase, otherwise lowercase. Then `join` up the string, and either log it to the console, or add it as the text content of another element as I've done here.

(I removed all the ids because an id needs to be unique, and they were mostly redundant here.)

```js
const output = document.querySelector('.output');
const spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');

// The array is _outside_ of the loop
const arr = [];

for (let i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {

  // Get a letter at the current index
  const letter = spans[i].textContent;

  // If it's zero uppercase the letter
  // otherwise lowercase it, and push it to
  // the array
  if (i === 0) {
    arr.push(letter.toUpperCase());
  } else {
    arr.push(letter.toLowerCase());  
  }
}

// `join` the array into a string, and
// either log it or add it as the text content
// of another element
output.textContent = arr.join('');
console.log(arr.join(''));
```

```html
<h1>
  <span>H</span>
  <span>o</span>
  <span>V</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>R</span>
  <span> </span>
  <span>O</span>
  <span>V</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>R</span>
  <span> </span>
  <span>M</span>
  <span>E</span>
  <span>!</span>
</h1>
<div class="output"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have correctly populated the text array (and noting you could probably combine the extraction and string build in a single loop), the direct answer is:

```
var letters;
for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    let letters += text[i].innerText;
}
console.log(letters);
```

Edited, based on comments & also probably we don't want to iteratively log the process of our loop, so moving the log out of the loop.

Comment: This will produce `&nbsp;` between the words and not whitespace because the OP actually put non-breaking spaces in those spans. Probably better to use `innerText`.

Comment: I just added the text array, its just a selectorAll on the document.

Comment: That's not what I meant. Theses `<span> </span>` actually have non-breaking spaces in the middle, not regular spaces, so `innerHTML` will give you `&nbsp;` and the end result would be `HoVER&nbsp;OVER&nbsp;ME!` which is not what the OP wanted according to their example.

Comment: Also, based on your latest change, which as per other comments is still invalid html, you are also going to miss the spaces completely, since they are not captured in your array.

Comment: Updated code, nothing mentioned here has worked.

Answer (score 0):

What about this solution:

```js
// Select the characters by the tag...
const letters = document.getElementsByTagName('span');

// ... or by the class name
// const letters = document.getElementsByClassName('letter');

// Your final string
let str = '';

// Iterate over array of letters
for (let char of letters) {
  // Write each single character into variable 'str'
  str += char.textContent;
}

// Your result
console.log(str);
```

```html
<!-- Don't apply same id to several elements, that's invalid HTML. Use classes instead -->
<h1>
  <span class="letter">H</span>
  <span class="letter">o</span>
  <span class="letter">V</span>
  <span class="letter">E</span>
  <span class="letter">R</span>
  <span> </span>
  <span class="letter">O</span>
  <span class="letter">V</span>
  <span class="letter">E</span>
  <span class="letter">R</span>
  <span> </span>
  <span class="letter">M</span>
  <span class="letter">E</span>
  <span class="letter">!</span>
</h1>
```